# Ubuntu Server 18.04 - NTFS partitions with 2048k cluster size not readable

Tags: partitioning, mount, ntfs

I have several 8TB hard drives pulled from a Windows machine that were formatted with NTFS partitions with 2048k cluster/allocation sizes. (I use the drives for storing only large files, so the large cluster size is more efficient.) For some reason they are not being recognized as NTFS partitions in Ubuntu.

I'm able to mount other NTFS partitions (with default cluster sizes) just fine.

*I'm noticing in Windows disk management each of the drives show a single NTFS partition, but when I drop it into my Ubuntu server the disk shows up with two partitions (non-NTFS).

`sudo blkid` shows:

> /dev/sdc1: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="96023799-cc2c-418b-a944-150529d8ee25"
>   /dev/sdc2: PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="7df2b7ae-4d42-419f-b57f-a6c9deac2a6f"

`sudo parted -l` shows:

> Model: ATA ST8000DM004-2CX1 (scsi)
>   Disk /dev/sdc: 8002GB
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
>   Partition Table: gpt
>   Disk Flags:
>   Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
>   1      17.4kB  134MB   134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
>   2      135MB   8002GB  8001GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata

Just found this which may explain the problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntfs-3g/+bug/1779427
I am getting the same error when I try to mount the partition:
`Unexpected sectors per cluster value (244).`

Comment: Can't you just reformat the drive? I mean, if you don't have any important data on it(them)?

Comment: No, they each have almost 8TB of data on them that I don't want to lose.

Comment: As per bug report: there is an [**experimental** package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/eoan/amd64/ntfs-3g/1:2017.3.23AR.3-3ubuntu1) available that fixes that bug.   **Dangerous, not posting as an answer...**